# Installation of Kivy Designer on Windows

Tags: kivy

I was trying to install kivy designer on windows. I followed the steps, but when I tried to run

```
python -m designer
```

I get the following error:

```
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.10.0
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.5.2 (v3.5.2:4def2a2901a5, Jun 25 2016, 22:01:18) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)]
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 194 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil, img_gif (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [OSC         ] using <thread> for socket
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL" graphics system
[INFO   ] [GL          ] GLEW initialization succeeded
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <glew>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'4.5.0 NVIDIA 376.54'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'NVIDIA Corporation'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'GeForce GTX 750/PCIe/SSE2'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 4, 5
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <b'4.50 NVIDIA'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <16384>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <32>
[INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\mokhoo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\runpy.py", line 184, in _run_module_as_main
     "__main__", mod_spec)
   File "C:\Users\mokhoo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
     exec(code, run_globals)
   File "C:\Users\mokhoo\Downloads\kivy-designer-master\kivy-designer\designer\__main__.py", line 3, in <module>
     from designer.app import DesignerApp
   File "C:\Users\mokhoo\Downloads\kivy-designer-master\kivy-designer\designer\app.py", line 14, in <module>
     from designer.components.dialogs.add_file import AddFileDialog
   File "C:\Users\mokhoo\Downloads\kivy-designer-master\kivy-designer\designer\components\dialogs\add_file.py", line 5, in <module>
     from kivy.garden.xpopup.file import XFileOpen, XFolder
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 636, in _load_backward_compatible
 KeyError: 'kivy.garden.xpopup'
```

Any ideas for easy way to install kivy on windows 64-bit?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Problem is solved by this:

```
garden install xpopup
```

Answer (score 1):

in CMD or powershell type

```
pip install -U watchdog pygments docutils jedi gitpython six kivy-garden

garden install xpopup
```

git clone http://github.com/kivy/kivy-designer

```
cd kivy-designer
python -m designer
```

tested with python 3.6

Answer (score 1):

**Problems is solved**

change environment path from

```
"C:\Program Files\Python36\" ==> C:\progra~1\Python36\
```

and run following command over the CMD or PS

```
pip install -U watchdog pygments docutils jedi gitpython six kivy-garden

garden install xpopup
```

then run

```
cd kivy-designer
python -m designer
```

**tested with python 3.6**